# Straighten Camera in Blender

Tags: transforms, camera

If I have a camera at 0/0/0 of the x/y/z and its heading is unknown.

How do I make it point in the direction of 1/0/0 quickly?

Comment: Rotate it 90 degrees, `R X 90`

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. The camera is located a 0/0/0 but the direction in which it points ("heading") is unknown. I want it to point towards 1/0/0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest way if you haven't applied any transforms on the camera is to reset the rotation with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to 0/0/0 and then rotate it 90° on the X and *-90°* on the Z, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> `90`, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `-90`.

If you have changed the transforms and can't reset it to 0/0/0, you can use exact measurements by using the **transform section** of the properties panel or the **object tab** in the properties view to rotate it *90°* on the X axis, *-90°* on the Z axis and *0°* on Y.

[image]